# Getting an error while connecting Azure file share

Tags: azure

> New-PSDrive : The network resource type is not correct
>
> At line:6 char:5
>
> - ```
>   New-PSDrive -Name U -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\rohitstore17. ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
> - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (U:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Answer (score 0):

I tried to  connect my azure file share and its working fine for me

Here are the steps i followed:
Created a file share inside storage account

[image]

And from Connect>select drive letter and copied the url and paste in Power shell which connected successfully.

[image]

[image]

If you are getting network issue while connecting ,You can create [private endpoint for your storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-networking-endpoints?tabs=azure-portal)  .

For more information please refer this GitHub link:  [Connect using New-PSDrive from the Portal (Azure File Share) needs fixing](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/23006) and Microsoft Documentation: [Mount SMB Azure file share on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows)